# Binding client to a server using sockets with a random port

Tags: c

I am trying to create a chat room between a server and multiple clients. Everything is fully functioning except binding the socket to a random port. I create a random port via

```c
server_info.sin_port = htons(0);
```

My issue lies on the client being able to use that port, or how can I send the port number to the client?

If i replace the port to a static number, such as '8888' the program works successfully. I am just having an issue with the client gathering the port.

Server code

```c
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);

    // Create socket
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (server_sockfd == -1) {
        char error[255];
        sprintf(error,"Fail to create a socket.");
    write(1,error,strlen(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Socket information
    struct sockaddr_in server_info, client_info;
    int s_addrlen = sizeof(server_info);
    int c_addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
    memset(&server_info, 0, s_addrlen);
    memset(&client_info, 0, c_addrlen);
    server_info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //TEST
    server_info.sin_port = htons(0);

    // Bind and Listen
    bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, s_addrlen);
    listen(server_sockfd, 5);

    // Print Server IP
    char start[100];
    getsockname(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_info, (socklen_t*) &s_addrlen);
    sprintf(start,"Start Server on: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr), ntohs(server_info.sin_port));
    write(1,start,strlen(start));
    // Initial linked list for clients
    root = newNode(server_sockfd, inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr));
    now = root;

    while (1) {
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_info, (socklen_t*) &c_addrlen);

        // Print Client IP
        getpeername(client_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_info, (socklen_t*) &c_addrlen);
    char client[255];
        sprintf(client,"Client %s:%d come in.\n", inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr), ntohs(client_info.sin_port));
    write(1,client,strlen(client));

        // Append linked list for clients
        ClientList *c = newNode(client_sockfd, inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr));
        c->prev = now;
        now->link = c;
        now = c;

        pthread_t id;
        if (pthread_create(&id, NULL, (void *)client_handler, (void *)c) != 0) {
            perror("Create pthread error!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client code

```c
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);

    // Naming
    char nick[255];
    sprintf(nick,"Please enter your name: ");
    write(1,nick,strlen(nick));
    if (fgets(nickname, LENGTH_NAME, stdin) != NULL) {
        str_trim_lf(nickname, LENGTH_NAME);
    }
    if (strlen(nickname) < 2 || strlen(nickname) >= LENGTH_NAME-1) {

      char nameerr[100];
      sprintf(nameerr,"\nName must be more than one and less than thirty characters.\n");
      write(1,nameerr,strlen(nameerr));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
      char err[100];
      sprintf(err,"Fail to create a socket.");
      write(1,err,strlen(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Socket information
    struct sockaddr_in server_info, client_info;
    int s_addrlen = sizeof(server_info);
    int c_addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
    memset(&server_info, 0, s_addrlen);
    memset(&client_info, 0, c_addrlen);
    server_info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    //TEST
     server_info.sin_port = htons(0);

    // Connect to Server
    int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, s_addrlen);
    if (err == -1) {
      char err[100];
      sprintf(err,"Connection to Server error!\n");
      write(1,err,strlen(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Names
    getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_info, (socklen_t*) &c_addrlen);
    getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_info, (socklen_t*) &s_addrlen);
    char conn[100];
    char ipval[100];
    sprintf(conn,"Connect to Server: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(server_info.sin_addr), ntohs(server_info.sin_port));
    sprintf(ipval,"You are: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr), ntohs(client_info.sin_port));
    write(1,conn,strlen(conn));
    write(1,ipval,strlen(ipval));

    send(sockfd, nickname, LENGTH_NAME, 0);

    pthread_t send_msg_thread;
    if (pthread_create(&send_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) send_msg_handler, NULL) != 0) {
      char err[100];
      sprintf (err,"Create pthread error!\n");
    write(1,err,strlen(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t recv_msg_thread;
    if (pthread_create(&recv_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) recv_msg_handler, NULL) != 0) {
      char err[100]; 
      sprintf(err,"Create pthread error!\n");
      write(1,err,strlen(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        if(flag) {
      char bye[20];
      sprintf(bye,"\nBye\n");
      write(1,bye,strlen(bye));
            break;
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is found by

```c
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, s_addrlen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the port number to the client the same way you send the IP address of the server.

In order to connect over TCP, the client needs to know the IP address and the non-zero port number of the server.

If the client and the server are running on the same computer, it's typical to use files, environment variables or the clipboard to communicate the IP address and the port number.

In your example, you can add a *printf* to server.c to print the IP address and the port number (get them using the function *getsockname*). Then you can add code to client.c to get the IP address from `argv[1]` and the port number from `argv[2]`. Once done with the code changes above, you start the server first, copy the printed IP address and port number to the clipboard, and paste it to the command-line of the client, then you press *Enter* to start the client, and it will get these 2 parameters in its `argv`.

Comment: Since I am already placing the port number into a buffer, could I just print the value to a temp txt file and sscanf it it to a value using atoi? Another thing is that I am using two different terminal sessions, one to run the server and one to run the client, so the client cant see anything printed to the terminal

Comment: @Matt Sure you can... `fprintf(file, "%u", port);` and `fscanf(file, "%u", &port)` is all you need once the file is open...

Comment: Is this good practice though? I feel like having a temp txt file is a bad solution compared to something easier.

Comment: @Matt: If you need a TCP connection from the client and the server, I think you probably won't find any simpler solutions than those in the answer. The last paragraph describes one of convenient practices I've observed multiple times in the last 20 years. If there was anything simpler, probably I'd remember and then mention it.